# Why does it make sense to talk about the first-quantized BRST formulation of a relativistic point particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, point-particles, brst

My question is about the BRST quantization of a point particle in Polchinski, Vol.1, Section 4.2.

The BRST quantization starts from the effective action for the gauge-fixed path-integral. But for the world-line approach of quantizing relativistic point particles, there is a problem.

There are no relativistic position operators, and therefore there are no position eigenstates $|x\rangle$ for relativistic point particles. This is one of the reasons why people abandoned the "relativistic quantum mechanics" and drifted towards quantizing field theory instead.

Considering this problem, the path-integral of a relativistic point particle does not make sense because $\langle t,x|t',x'\rangle$ is not defined. Does it make any physical sense to talk about the BRST quantization of a relativistic point particle? Is the section of the BRST quantization of a relativistic point particle in Polchinski merely a heuristic example for pedagogical purposes?

Comment: Where in the corresponding section of Polchinski do you think the existence of position eigenstates is needed? Please include the relevant parts into the question so that one may answer the question without opening Polchinski. Note also that the $X^\mu(\tau)$ coordinates of the relativistic point particle are *not* position operators in the sense that is prohibited by relativity.

Comment: Can you elaborate the last sentence of your comment?

Comment: The theory "of the relativistic point particle" doesn't know that it is a relativistic point particle. Purely formally, it's a theory of 4 scalar fields $X^\mu$ living on a 1-dimensional spacetime parameterized by $\tau$. There are certain assumptions that go into the no-go theorems for relativistic position operators that these scalar fields simply don't fulfill (and they don't lend themselves to being interpreted as actual position operators, consequently). As I said, please edit your question to pinpoint the exact step in the BRST procedure that you think fails.

Comment: I already said it in my post. I thought that there is no way to define $|X^{\mu}>$ and therefore I thought that it does not make sense to talk about the BRST quantization of a relativistic point particle.

Comment: Isn't it faster to just quantise the point particle for yourself @XiaoyiJing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there maybe a misunderstanding that is greatly clarified by the BRST method as presented in Polchinsky. It avoids the discussion in Ticciati's book since it contains a position operator in 4 rather than 3 dimensions. The Kinematical Hilbert space obtained by quantizing the action

$$S=\int d\lambda\left(\frac{1}{2}(\dot{x}^2+m^2)-\dot{b}c\right)$$

yields the operators $X^\mu$, $P_\mu$, $B$ and $C$ satisfying the canonical commutation relations $[X^\mu,P_\nu]=\delta^\mu_\nu$ and $\{B,C\}=1$. From Stone-von Neumann theorem, we know that there is a unique irreducible representation of these on the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$ where $(X^\mu\psi)(x)=x^\mu\psi(x)$ and $(P_\mu\psi)(x)=-i\hbar\partial_\mu\psi(x)$. In particular, the Dirac delta $|x\rangle=\delta_{x}$, satisfying $(X^\mu\delta_x)(y)=y^\mu\delta(x-y)=x^\mu\delta(x-y)=x^\mu\delta_x(y)$, i.e. $X^\mu|x\rangle=x^\mu|x\rangle$, is in the theory. The set of such states are orthogonal.

Now, the canonical quantization procedure also yields the Hamiltonian $H=\frac{1}{2}(p^2+m^2)$ and the BRST operator $Q=cH$. Physical states are  those for which $Q\psi=0$, i.e. those for which $H\psi=0$. Via Schrödinger's equation, a state $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow L^2(M)$ evolving in the parameter $\lambda$ which is physical would then satisfy $i\hbar\frac{d\phi(\lambda)}{d\lambda}=H\phi(\lambda)=0$, which is precisely what we want! States should not depend on the unphysical parameter $\lambda$. Indeed, a state $\psi\in L^2(M)$ already corresponds to the whole worldline of the particle. Now, we see that eventhough we do have a position operator and vectors $|x\rangle$, the latter are unphysical since they are not BRST closed.

Incidentally, $H\psi=0$ is the Klein-Gordon equation. Usually, it is claimed in QFT classes that this is not a satisfactory equation for a wave function since the norm obtained by integrating over three space is not conserved. However, we now see that the real norm must be obtained by integrating over the whole four dimensional space, which doesn't lead to any trouble. On the other hand, the conserved quantity given by the Klein-Gordon Lagrangian doesn't have to be interpreted as a probability density but rather as a charge density. Then there is no problem with the fact that it is not positive definite.

Let me note that BRST quantization does seem to be important for this analysis. If one tries to quantize a gauge fixed action like $$S=-m\int\sqrt{1-\|\vec{v}\|^2}$$ directly, one gets to a Schrödinger equation $$i\hbar\frac{d\phi}{dt}=\sqrt{-\hbar^2\Delta+m^2}\phi(t)$$ which is non-local. I don't really know what is happening here but I guess this is why people use BRST quantization.

I hope I didn't miss any obvious details of something that makes my arguments invalid hahahah. Let me finalize by stating that

1. I don't know of a way to introduce interactions into this constructions. If there is, it should only be possible for very specific interactions which wouldn't violate particle number conservation. This is why QFT is very important to describe the interesting part of the relativistic theory of particles. One can however do perturbative QFT in a "first quantized" point of view using the action above and Feynman diagrams, thus bypassing the need of say the Klein-Gordon action.
2. This "first quantized" point of view is very important for string theory where the string field theory (the analogue of Klein-Gordon for the spinless relativistic particle) is difficult to obtain, but the analog of the action above (the Polyakov action) is readily available.

I don't really understand much of string theory but those two remarks where made in my class.

Comment: I omitted the part of the Hilbert space regarding the C and B for simplicity. The part we don't want coming from this is eliminated by identifying all BRST exact states.

Comment: No problem! I've also started convincing myself that the description leading to the non-local Hamiltonian is equivalent to the one obtained with the BRST procedure. The unitary transformation from the first to the physical Hilbert space of the second is precisely obtained by mapping every wave function $\psi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ to its time evolved $\phi:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$. Of course, one needs to check that $\phi\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^4)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are not right. There is no orthogonal basis $|x,t\rangle$ for fixed $t$ in relativistic quantum mechanics, but there is a state $|x,t\rangle=|x^{\mu}\rangle$. In quantum field theory this state is expressed by $\phi(x)|0\rangle$, but this is a one-particle state, so can be expressed in the one-particle space, spanned by the momenta eigenstates $|\vec{p}\rangle$.

$$
|x^{\mu}\rangle=(2\pi)^{-3/2}\int \frac{d^{3}\vec{p}}{\sqrt{2E_p}}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}|\vec{p}\rangle
$$

The main point is that the state $|x\rangle$ does not imply the existence of a hermitian operator $x$, so this state can exist without the existence of $x$-operator. In fact, this operator can't exist since the Hamiltonian is bounded from bellow. You can see more about it [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386645/what-wavefunctions-do-the-creation-operator-of-a-massive-real-scalar-free-field/386651#386651).

If the state $|x^{\mu}\rangle$ exist, makes perfect sense to have path integrals over trajectories $x_{\mu}(\tau)$, if we gauge away the parametrization at the end.

$$
\langle x_2^{\mu}|x_1^{\mu}\rangle=\int_{x(0)=x_1}^{x(1)=x_2}\frac{\left[dx(\tau)\right]}{\mathbb{diff}}\,e^{-S[x]}
$$

What you will discover from that path integral is that $\langle x_2|x_1\rangle \neq 0$ even for space-like intervals, and by Lorentz symmetry you may deduce that the same happens for hyper-surface of simultaneity. This means that we cannot take $|x\rangle \rightarrow |\vec{x},t\rangle$ as an orthogonal basis for $t$ fixed.

This is why there is no wave function $\psi(x)$ description for the states. For the momentum wave-function there will be no problem, and a wave-function  $\phi(p)$ is totally acceptable. For instance, $P$ is a hermitian operator for the one-particle Hilbert space in the free theory (free means no mixing with multi-particles states).

Actually the BRST-approach is far from be just pedagogical. You can obtain the field theory description by defining a field operator $\Psi(x^{\mu})$ and impose the equation of motion:

$$
Q\Psi=0
$$

This is useful to obtain non-linear generalization (i.e. how to put interactions) for particles in the presence of supersymmetry and/or gauge symmetry. The gauge transformations of the field will be described by the generalization of the BRST-exact fields $\delta\Psi=Q\Lambda+g\left[\Psi,\Lambda\right]$ and the equation of motion will be:

$$
Q\Psi + g\Psi^2=0\,.
$$

You can see more about it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09966).

Comment: I've seen some books saying that the local states cannot be defined in relativistic quantum mechanics.  [Theory of Group Representations and Applications by A.O. Barut](https://www.amazon.com/Theory-Group-Representations-Applications-Barut/dp/9971502178) 

As far as I could remember, it's from induced representation theory of Poincare algebra. Perhaps you are not right.

Comment: You cannot make state localized in the sense of  $|x,t\rangle$ and $|y,t\rangle$ being orthogonal each other, i.e. localize a particle in a *single* point in space. But there is nothing prohibiting the existence of state $|x^{\mu}\rangle$ that have the right Poincare transformation. Actually this state is unique!

Comment: You can check that this is the state $\phi(x)|0\rangle$, but you can also work out the $p$ basis and construct the state 
$$
|x^{\mu}\rangle=\int \frac{d^{3}\vec{p}}{\sqrt{2E_p}}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}|\vec{p}\rangle
$$

Comment: But from the book "Theory of Group Representations and Applications by A.O. Barut ", it clearly says that the localized state cannot be defined. States are defined from the representation of the Poincare algebra from that book. Also, I just found another book talking about this issue, [An Interpretive Introduction to Quantum Field Theory](http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/9789812776440_0007) on page 50-51. It's related with uncertainty principle.

Comment: I think that you are not understanding what they are saying,. Localized states are not $|x^{\mu}\rangle$, are states that are eigenstates of $\vec{x}$, and this two things are completely different.

Comment: There is another book talking about this problem. [Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians R. TICCIATI](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/quantum-field-theory-for-mathematicians/4783BB717856D3572422F05714CA3D5A) in section 1.6. It talks about the position eigenstate in non-relativistic quantum mechanics, and why it cannot be generalized in relativistic quantum mechanics.

Comment: Just try to understand the state that I wrote. Do boost, translation on this state and check that this state behaves under this transformations as $x^{\mu}$. Again, this is not a localized state.

Comment: In the above book "Quantum Field Theory for Mathematicians R. TICCIATI", the author says the following: 

The outcome, then, is that a position operator is inconsistent with relativity.

Comment: Why isn't it a localized state? I think it is localized at $x^{\mu}$, isn't it?

Comment: The operator $x^{\mu}$ does not exist!!!, the state $|x^{\mu}\rangle$ is NOT a eigenstate of $x^{\mu}$ because this operator does not exist at first place. What defines this state $|x^{\mu}\rangle$ is the properties under Lorentz transformations. Please, see this [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/386645/what-wavefunctions-do-the-creation-operator-of-a-massive-real-scalar-free-field/386651#386651](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/386645/)

Comment: what happens if you take an space-like slice of positions and construct a projection operator by summing all the projector operators of all the |$x^\mu$> states? Isn't that the same as a local basis at some constant t?

Comment: @lurscher this is the striking point. The states $|x^{\mu}\rangle$ in ANY space-like surface are not orthogonal each other. This means that they don't provide a basis, and that projectors $|x\rangle\langle x|$ and $|y\rangle\langle y|$ will not commute!!! This means that there is no way to determine **exclusively** the position of the particle. In other words, asking if the particle is at $x$ or asking if the particle is at $y$ are incompatible quantum mechanically.

Comment: And no hermitian operator of the type $\hat{x}=\sum_x x |x\rangle\langle x|$ is possible since $|x\rangle$ is not a basis

Comment: Why is it a one-particle state?

Comment: The state $\phi(x)|0\rangle$ is a one-particle state. If you prefer to start with $|x\rangle$ without fields, by working the superposition on $|p\rangle$ basis, then this will be a one-particle by construction ;)

Comment: I think an 1p state is $|p>$.

Comment: and all the superpostions made of it, like $$ |x^{\mu}\rangle=\int \frac{d^{3}\vec{p}}{\sqrt{2E_p}}e^{ip_{\mu}x^{\mu}}|\vec{p}\rangle $$

Comment: How do I see that this is an eigenstate of the number operator?

Comment: To have an operator associated to the number of particles you need to go to the Field Theory. There, the number of particles will be $\sum_{p} a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{p}$, as you can see, this state is an eigenvector of it since $ a_{p}^{\dagger}a_{p}|p'\rangle = \delta_{p\,p'}|p\rangle$

Comment: $|p>$ is an one-particle state defined in quantum field theory.